# How to have a notification of expired Facebook user access token

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I've seen a lot of examples, and read some articles to know well about the access token expiration and it was explained pretty well in this article, [Access Token Expiration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/).

I know how to renew the expiration access token. However, the problem is that, as explained in the article, there are possibly 4 reasons for expiration of access token .

Hence, there is no certainty when the access token will be expired and it can be at anytime. The conventional solution is by using offline_permision which will be deprecated by FB soon.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Once the access token expired, and while when user is using our facebook app, I want FB to notifies me.
2. Once receiving notification, renew the access token.

I don't think the following achieves what I want.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
     alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});
```

Hence, is there any way to have notification from FB when the access token is expired ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to access the API with an expired token, Facebook will send back an error message.  You just check for that error in your callback function that handles the Facebook response, and if an error exists, refresh the token and try the API call again.

From Facebook:

> Facebook **doesn't notify you that a previously issued access token has become invalid**. Unless you have persisted the expiry time passed to your application along with the access token, often the first your application knows that a given token has become invalid is when you attempt to make a request to the API.

Comment: Yeah, I know Facebook will return the response. I prefer event based notification, means when it expires for any reason, it will kinda notify, through FB.event subscribe something.

But, as you helped to highlight that Facebook doesn't notify. hmnn...Okay, make it the other way, what about to extend the expiration to at least a day ?? What about that?

Comment: You could create you own notification service with a looping interval, but that seems like it really isn't helpful as you still need to handle the error if the token expires in-between intervals.

As for extending the token, unfortunately that isn't really possible. You do get an expiry time with the token (most of the time) so you could do something with that maybe (set an event to refresh the token just before it is supposed to expire) but again, it could still expire early.

I agree it would be nice to have an event fired that we could subscribe to through FB.event.subscribe